# Dart Map comprehension

Tags: dart

In python I'd write:

```py
{a:0 for a in range(5)}
```

to get

```
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}
```

How can I achieve the same in Dart?

So far I have this:

```dart
List<Map<String, double>>.generate(5, (i) => { i: 0 });
```

but this generates list of maps `[{0: 0}, {1: 0}, {2: 0}, {3: 0}, {4: 0}]`,

while I want a simple map

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dart has a **collection for** syntax that is similar to Python's comprehensions.  The [Dart Language Tour provides examples for `List`s](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists), but it can be used for `Set`s and `Map`s too:

```dart
final map = {for (var a = 0; a < 5; a += 1) a: 0};
```

You can consult the [feature specification](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.3/control-flow-collections/feature-specification.md) for more details.

Comment: You always bring out something out of blue :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<int, int> map = {};
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  map[i] = 0;
}
```

Prints

```
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}
```

---

**Edit:**

You can also try this approach:

```
List<int> list1 = List.generate(5, (i) => i);
List<int> list2 = List.generate(5, (i) => 0);
var map = Map.fromIterables(list1, list2);
```

Comment: Is there a way to create it "inline" / in one line?

Comment: You can always make a function out of it. Don't make it a target being it a one-liner if it makes the code less readable.

Comment: Just a tip: You second solution does use more memory and you don't need to create lists since `fromIterables` takes `Iterable` as argument. So it is more efficient to use `Iterable.generate(5, (i) => i)` and `Iterable.generate(5, (_) => 0)`.

Comment: @julemand101 I agree `Iterables` are better in terms of performance, but generally it limits user to have more functionality which `List` provides, so to make the answer easy to understand and more usable I used `List`

Comment: @Caramiriel, thank you for good advice. Although I agree with you on code readability, my goal here was to get to know how to create one-liner Map. Not being able to do it made me feel handicapped.

Comment: This solution reassembles `zip` method in Python. Is it same?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way if you want a solution using one line:

```
void main() {
  final map = Map.fromEntries(Iterable.generate(5, (i) => MapEntry(i, 0)));
  print(map); // {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}
}
```